# Is there cryptsetup android binary

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, encryption

One thing I badly need on android is support for opening Luks volumes. Is there a cryptsetup / cryptfs binary so, I can execute it from terminal on a rooted phone to mount luks volumes.

Please donot suggest apps for opening luks volumes , like Luks Manager. Im having rooted phone on android 5.0.2.

I wish the functionality is built into the kernel itself.

Answer (score 1):

I use [LUKS Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nemesis2.luksmanager)'s binary on the command line.